# Sum in PHP with HTML Form using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, sum

I am new with jquery and want to create a very very simple page to learn a bit about. I am trying to make a form that sends its values to php. Php sum it and returns the results. Jquery show it in the page, dynamically.

This is my html and javascript:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>null</title> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function(){ 

$("form1").change(function() { 

$.get("requisit.php", {a1: $("#a1").html(), a2: $("#a2").html()}, 

function(data) { 

$(".results").empty().html(data); 

}); 

return false; 
}); 
}); 
</script> 

</head> 
<body>         

<form name="form1"> 
<input type="text" name="a11" id="a1"><br/>
<input type="text" name="a22" id="a2">
</form> 

<div class="results"> 
The answer is: 
</div> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

This is my php:

```
<?php 
$a1 = $_GET['a1']; 
$a2 = $_GET['a2']; 

$sasa = $a1+$a2; 
echo $sasa; 
?>
```

AJAX was not displaying results. That's my problem. I am trying to make AJAX detect any modification and show results but it does not work and I dont know why.

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you getting hung up? PHP doesnt return the right result? AJAX results don't display, etc.

Comment: @Hitoshi You need to use the `.val()` method to get the value of the fields instead of `.html()`

Comment: @cris85 PHP result correctly if you test it. AJAX does not display nothing...

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html> 
<head> 
<title>null</title> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function(){ 

$(".sum").keyup(function() { 

totalamount=0;

$('.sum').each(function()
{
    if($(this).val()!=""){

    totalamount += parseFloat($(this).val());
}

});

$(".results").html(totalamount );

}); 
}); 
</script> 

</head> 
<body>         

<form name="form1"> 
<input type="text" name="a11" class="sum" id="a1"><br/>
<input type="text" name="a22" class="sum" id="a2">
</form> 

<div class="results"> 
The answer is: 
</div> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

You can try this code:
You need to take a common class of each textarea box and use $('.sum').each(function()

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Vikas Umrao. In your answer PHP was not used, only JS. I am trying to make AJAX send the data to PHP, PHP calculates and AJAX display it in the page. If have any modification, AJAX detects and change the results again.